# ¿Cómo puedo modificar mi html desde mi javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que pasa es que estoy intentando acceder a mi `input` en mi formulario y asignarle los valores que recibo de mi `json` de `php`, lo he intentado de diversas formas pero no he podido:
este es el `json` que estoy recibiendo en r:

`{id_producto: "247", nombre_producto: "probando", descripcion_producto: "123", tipo_producto: "10"}`

Aquí hago la petición con `ajax`:

```
$(".editarProducto").click(function () {
    $("#formulario_productos").hide();
    var id_producto = $(this).next(".id_producto").val();
    var datosproducto = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: { id_producto: id_producto, funcion: "editarProducto" },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            $.each(r, function (index, value) {
                datosproducto.push(value);
                //alert(index + ": " + value);
            });
            $('#nombre_editar_producto').val(datosproducto[1]);
            var valor = $('#nombre_editar_producto').val();
            console.log(valor);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert("no se han podido obtener los parametros");
        }
    });
    /*var inputNombre = document.getElementById("nombre_editar_producto");
    inputNombre.value = "probando";*/

    $("#formulario_editar_productos").load();
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").show();
});
```

Y este es el formulario que estoy intentando modificar:

```
<form action="" id="formulario_productos" method="post" class="text-center" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label  class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nombre Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input required type="text" class="form-control nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" autocomplete="off" id="nombre_producto" name="nombre_producto" placeholder="Nombre Producto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label  class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Reseña Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input required type="text" class="form-control descripcion_producto" autocomplete="off" id= "descripcion_producto" name="descripcion_producto" placeholder="Descripcion Producto">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label  class="col-sm-4">Tipo de Producto:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <select class="form-control tipo_producto" id="tipo_producto" name="tipo_producto">
                    {foreach item=tipoProducto from=$arrayTipoProducto}
                        <option value="{$tipoProducto.id_tipo_producto}">{$tipoProducto.nombre_tipo_producto}</option>
                    {/foreach}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-center"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block guardarProductos" onclick="name()" name="guardadoProductos" value="GUARDAR">
        </div>        
    </form>
```

El `input` nombre producto y reseña producto son los que estoy intentando reemplazar con los valores del `json`, agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes solo acceder con `r.nombre_producto` para obtener el valor

**Ejemplo:**

```
success: function (r) {

            $('#nombre_producto').val(r.nombre_producto);
            var valor = $('#nombre_producto').val();
            console.log(valor);
        },
```

También tienes definido dos `id="nombre_producto"` en tu `input`

Comment: uffff de nuevo muchas gracias me has salvado

Answer (score 1):

Si el valor de `r` es el que indicas, no es necesario recorrerlo. Deberías asignar el valor directamente. Así quedaría el javascript:

```
$(".editarProducto").click(function () {
    $("#formulario_productos").hide();
    var id_producto = $(this).next(".id_producto").val();
    var datosproducto = [];
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: { id_producto: id_producto, funcion: "editarProducto" },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            // Quitamos el bucle
            /*$.each(r, function (index, value) {
                datosproducto.push(value);
                //alert(index + ": " + value);
            });*/

            // Añadimos el valor directamente a 'nombre_editar_producto'
            $('#nombre_editar_producto').val(r.nombre_producto);
            var valor = $('#nombre_editar_producto').val();
            console.log(valor);
        },
        error: function (r) {
            alert("no se han podido obtener los parametros");
        }
    });
    /*var inputNombre = document.getElementById("nombre_editar_producto");
    inputNombre.value = "probando";*/

    $("#formulario_editar_productos").load();
    $("#formulario_editar_productos").show();
});
```